# Import modules from folder-based npm dependency

Tags: node.js, npm

My project contains three subprojects. The `shared` subproject is used by the other subprojects:

```
- myproject
  - server
      node_modules
      package.json
  - client
      node_modules
      package.json
  - shared
      node_modules
      package.json         the name property is "shared"
      foo.ts
      bar.ts
```

I want to reference the `shared` subproject. I don't like the `npm link` approach as it has drawbacks (package duplication). So I tried the `npm install <folder>` [approach](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install):

```
cd server
npm i ../shared
cd ..
cd client
npm i ../shared
```

That adds `"shared": "file:../shared"` to the two main `project.json` files. Good.

BUT... How do I reference modules from the common subproject? I tried:

```
import * as foo from "foo";
import * as foo from "shared/foo";
import shared from "shared";
// and other combinations...
```

I don't want to use `"../../../../../shared/node_modules/shared/foo/bar/baz"` as that defeats the purpose of this approach. What is the clean/proper way to do this?

Comment: Can you share the `tsconfig.json` for the `shared` project? (guessing from the filenames that you're using TypeScript)

Comment: @ecraig12345 It doesn't work whether there is a tsconfig or not (though I tried with a standard/minimal tsconfig and it didn't help). My goal was not to compile that shared module anyway - I want to somehow import it into the actual server/client projects. Is it even possible?

Comment: If this doesn't work, what is the point of `npm i folder` and `npm link folder` what purpose do they serve if I can't import from them? I must be missing something or using the wrong syntax??